# How to set Django-allAuth for Google OAuth2 to only able to login with company email address

Tags: django, google-oauth, django-allauth, django-socialauth

As of now any user with gmail account are able to log in in my django application , whereas I want to restrict the user with company domain can only login through gmail in my application.

```
example:
Allowed:
    akashrathor@example.com
    xyz@xyzcompany.com
    abcdefgh@abccompany.com
not allowed:
    abcd@gmail.com
```

as far as my settings.py are set as:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
]

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details'
)
SOCIAL_AUTH_DISCONNECT_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.disconnect.get_entries',
    'social.pipeline.disconnect.revoke_tokens',
    'social.pipeline.disconnect.disconnect'
)
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
]

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'online',
        }
    }
}

SITE_ID = 1
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path,include
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView
urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('logout', LogoutView.as_view(),name="logout"),
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit Google OAuth access to one domain using 'hd' param (Django / python-social-auth)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38566799/limit-google-oauth-access-to-one-domain-using-hd-param-django-python-social)

Comment: NO!, I don't want to restrict to known domain. domains could be of any numbers, I just  want user with email address ending with 'gmail.com' will be redirected to error page, with error message - > that only company domain can signup.

Comment: You are mixing applications, one thing is `python-social-auth` and another is `django-allauth`.

Comment: Alright! I changed the question statement now. Do you know the solution of it. As I am still struggling to find appropriate solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47745878/14457833